# How to create custom indicator? Slope of the line of 50 day EMA

Tags: r, plot, quantmod, moving-average, technical-indicator

I have been creating a few technical indicators using Quantmod's NewTa function.
I've been trying to create a custom indicator that ideally should be charted using `ChartSeries`. This indicator should show the slope of the line of the 50 day EMA of the adjusted closing price.

```
getSymbols("NOVO-B.CO")
p <- na.omit('NOVO-B.CO')
FiftyEMA <- function(x){


MA <- removeNA((EMA(p[,6],n=50)))

}
SlopeFiftyEMA <- function(x){
  run=(FiftyEMA(y)/FiftyEMA(x))
}
Slope.Indicator <- newTA(SlopeFiftyEMA,legend.name = "50 Day EMA Slope of Line Indicator")
Slope.Indicator()
```

This gives me the error: Error in get.current.chob() : improperly set or missing graphics device

I also tried a new code that gives me an actual INDICATOR! Please let me know what you think (if you think it looks correct or not):

First I export the data to excel: (the stock data is still denoted as `p`)

```
write.csv(p,"data")
```

## import data

```
x <- data[,1]
y <- data[,7]
MA <- removeNA(EMA(y,n=50))
length(MA)
```

## length of MA = 1923

```
l=1:1923
SlopeFiftyEMA <- function(x){
(diff(MA)/diff(l))
}
Slope.Indicator <- newTA(SlopeFiftyEMA,legend.name = "50 Day EMA Slope of Line Indicator")
twelvemonths="last 12 months"
chartSeries(p,subset = twelvemonths,theme = 'white',up.col = 'blue',dn.col = 'grey',name ="Custom Indicators")
Slope.Indicator()
```

[image: Custom Indicator on the Chart]

Any Input anyone? Last time I posted there was no indicator

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first error seems to exist because you don't call `chartSeries` before calling `Slope.indicator()`.  But your code is a bit messy, including not defining `y` (maybe you introduce it later in import data).

The approach presented here will plot the slope of the MA according to linear regression, using `chart_Series` (arguably cleaner plots than the original `chartSeries`).  Two types of slopes are computed, including the one you proposed, which is the differences of the EMA.

```
getSymbols(c("NOVO-B.CO"))

x <- `NOVO-B.CO`
x[, c(1:4, 6)] <- na.locf(x[, c(1:4, 6)])
x$EMA <- EMA(Cl(x), n = 50)
x <- merge(x, rollSFM(Ra = x[, "EMA"], Rb = 1:NROW(x), n = 20))

x <- merge(x, setNames(diff(x$EMA), "diff1"))

chart_Series(x, subset = "2016/")
add_TA(x$EMA, on = 1, col = "purple")
# Plot the slope of the MA:
add_TA(x$beta, col = "green")
# Plot the 1 lag diff of the moving average:
add_TA(x$diff1, lty = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a bunch (again). I agree with you the Chart_Series call produces nicer charts than ChartSeries does. However, it doesn't provide as many built in TAs. Thanks again though

Comment: FXQuantTrader, what does this code do? x[, c(1:4, 6)] <- na.locf(x[, c(1:4, 6)])

Comment: c(1:4, 6) gives the indices 1,2,3,4,6.  So x[, c(1:4, 6)]  returns 5 columns in total (it doesn't return the 5th column).  These columns are then having any NA values in them filled forward with the most recent non NA observation in the same column (which is `na.locf(x[, c(1:4, 6)])`).  Try reading about `?na.locf`.